# Ckeditor error 500 in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor, production-environment

I have the following problem only production with ckeditor gem

```
ActionView::Template::Error (No input found for ckeditor):
 9:   <% end %>
10:
11:   <div class="inputs clearfix">
12:     <%= f.input :content, as: :ckeditor, input_html: { ckeditor: {toolbar: 'Basic'} }  %>
13:   </div>
14:
15:   <div class="clear-row h10"></div>
```

I am using SimpleForm, rails, the gem is installed, the rake tasks to copy nodigest assets and this https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/issues/91 doesn't work for me

Comment: Have you checked this ? https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/issues/91

Comment: Have you read the whole GH issue @Slawek suggested? At the end it's a possible cause (having the gem in the assets group in the Gemfile). Anyway if this is not the cause you must provide more info (what versions of the gems, maybe a sample rails app with the exception)